Green's theorem Laplacian why the minus sign?
In the book Orthogonal Polynomials of several variables', Charles_F._Dunkl,_Yuan_Xu p.117 is written i paste here

It may sound like a stupid question but would it not also be true without the minus signs or change them to + ? Anyway assuming yes then any particular reason why he uses the minus sign. I tend to recall other uses of Green's theorem where the minus sign is needed as in
$\int L dx+M dy= \int \!\int(dM/dx-dL/dy)\; dx\,dy $ where integral lhs is contour integral and rhs is over one dimension higher. And do understand why the minus sign is needed there. Parenthetically in that last which i wrote, but is also usually written in that or similar form in textbooks etc., why need separate functions L and M. Could it not just be written as
$\int L dx+L dy= \int \!\int(dL/dx-dL/dy)\; dx\,dy$ ? Anyway there is another general text book expression which has a necessary minus sign but i cannot now find that expression. Think it had something involving Laplacian or divergence of gradient on the product of 2 functions and integrals or something like that in vector analysis. Does anyone recall that or similar application of Green's function ? Now that i think about it more perhaps he uses the minus signs in his proposition to show that spherical harmonics of different degree are orthogonal, actually he makes that note, later. Think the reason he is correct and only correct in his last expression is because he is assuming UNIT hyper-sphere and would not be true without that assumption in general ?
To make it easier i should have added that here by the ball $B^d$ is meant unit hypersphere and $S^{d-1}$ is surface of such and he is assuming d>2. I at first hurriedly thinking could prove it perhaps by just changing the sign of one functions but obviously that does not accomplish anything.
What i really wanted to do is to show that it is true for each function separately so then in that case the sign should not matter. I should be able to determine or guesstimate that pretty easily by simple example and if it is not then almost for sure it is not going to be true with minus signs changed to plus.
Also as surprisingly heard now not all those Green's ... are generally applicable nor the name of same person. Seems long ago in schools had read $\nabla^2 or \Delta$ acting on $1/r\!=\!-cst*delta(r=0) $ where cst is positive usually depending upon dimensions and involving pi for d>2. I think the cst may be 4*pi in 3 dimensions. I thought this and integral of divergence of gradient of some function was equal to normal derivative of it on a surface was example of Green's function and was so related and to also Green's theorem etc. so had to be the same person but i guess not according to another person. Anyway not concerned with these nomenclature issues but would be satisfied by a simple example or otherwise example of polynomials f,g for which it is false. That is that one cannot change the minus sign to plus in his proposition.

I don't fully understand what you're asking.  Could you write explicitly the statement that you think might be true, and explain your attempt to prove or disprove it?  Also, your last paragraph is somewhat vague and rambling.  I'd suggest rewriting to make it more clear and concise.

Also, please review the tags you are using.  This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Green's functions or Green's relations; they are unrelated to Green's theorem.

Please read the tag descriptions: "[greens-function] This tag is for questions about a Green's function which is the impulse response of an inhomogeneous differential equation defined on a domain, with specified initial conditions or boundary conditions."  "[greens-relations] In abstract algebra, Green's relations are five equivalence relations that characterise the elements of a semigroup in terms of the principal ideals they generate. Use it along with (semi-group) and (abstract-algebra). DO NOT confuse it with (greens-theorem) or (greens-identities). "

Those concepts do not have anything to do with your question.

Though i can also think of why atleast his first statement in the proposition would not have to necessarily be related to Green's... but rather that the integral of derivative is equal to the original function but with a few more details in explanation or proof ? But that's what he wrote anyway "...Green's...".

If you change $f$ to $-f$ then you must do so throughout; you then have $\frac{\partial(-f)}{\partial n} = - \frac{\partial f}{\partial n}$ and $\Delta(-f) = -\Delta f$ because they are linear operators.  This just negates both entire sides of the equation, but the two terms still have opposite signs.

if u don't think it has anything to do with Green's then write to the authors of the book and ask them why they used the words 'Green's function'.

I fully agree it is related to Green's THEOREM.  I am saying that it has nothing to do with Green's FUNCTIONS or Green's RELATIONS.  The latter is not even named after the same person.

The book said "Green's theorem", not "Green's function".  I have no objection to "Green's" - it's the word that follows it.

Ok so now then you are saying it is NOT valid if changed the minus signs to plus ?

I don't know whether it is or not - I haven't thought through it carefully.  But it's not trivially equivalent in the way you are thinking.

When $d=1$, then $B^n=[-1,1]$ and $S^n={-1,1}$, with orientation. Now what happens with the book's presentation and your proposed alternate version if $f(x)=x^m$ and $g(x)=x^n$?

My answer was in 2 dim's, d=2, and chose an easy way to show it for that. Any convex region and boundary can be approximated from many squares and the boundary as line segments along the x and y axis as close to the real boundary for approximation as needed and the error goes to zero as the number of squares goes to inf. for any polynomial. Since chose random integers for all and any polynomials can be expanded as infinite series in terms of sum of products of each function alone. The extension to hypercubes approximating goes along these same ideas as presented in my non rigorous example.

ok i guess u would have questioned my first answer as i did not give enough or any detail. Now have added more to the first answer but the 2nd last answer is the one that i was looking for as i expressed in the question.

You've lost me. This whole question is proposing an "alternate version" to this book's Proposition 4.1.5 using addition to replace the subtraction there, but you are denying an "alternate version". You say something about needing $d\gt2$, but I see nothing about that in the post. I wish you luck finding whatever you are trying to find.

NO i was not proposing an alternate version. u got it all mixed up and wrong as to my question. I don't see where i said alternate version in the first place but anyway if i did then what i was looking for was the last pasted from Jackson electrodynamics answer i gave. And by the way scratch that comment i made about yours not being harmonic as that was irrelevant.

Ok actually the d>2 was in the book before that proposition but now does not matter anyway as your example just proves the same also for one dim. atleast for m,n positive or non-neg. integers.

and u may could extend that one dimensional case to higher dimensions using smaller and smaller line segments.

NOw here is what i was looking for in 3 dimensions from J D Jackson electrodynamics.
And now one can clearly see the question has very much to do with Green's identities and since involves also divergence of gradient and integrals then it is also related to Green's function as i will paste here a couple pages or so afterward.


Ok did a simple test on the 2 dimensional square and showed the expressions are NOT true individually but the difference is which is sufficient to show by obvious extensions that the minus sign is necessary and cannot be replaced by plus. Ok guess need more detail so here is a program in maxima which gave the answer true.
/'Orthog poly's several var's 117 show the minus sign is necessary and plus is not valid under prop 4.1.5. by simple analogy
to unit square in 2 dimensions analogy which could be expanded into any higher dim. hypercube /
(fl:true,for a:2 thru 4 do for b:3 thru 5 do for k:3 thru 4 do for m thru 4 do(f:x^ay^b,g:x^my^k,ii:integrate(integrate(g*(diff(f,x,2)+diff(f,y,2
)),x,0,1),y,0,1)-integrate(integrate(f*(diff(g,x,2)+diff(g,y,2)),x,0,1),y,0,1),gs:lratsubst(x=1,g),fs:lratsubst(x=1,diff(f,x)),is:integrate(gsfs,y,0
,1)  ,gt:lratsubst(y=1,g) ,ft:lratsubst(y=1,diff(f,y)), it:integrate(gtft,x,0,1),gs:lratsubst(x=1,diff(g,x)),fs:lratsubst(x=1,f),iss:integrate(gsfs,y,0,1)
,gt:lratsubst(y=1,f),ft:lratsubst(y=1,diff(g,y)),itt:integrate(gtft,x,0,1), if it+is-iss-itt-ii#0 then fl:false
/,disp([a,b,k,m,"fs",fs,"gs",gs,"is",is,"it",it,"it+is-iss-itt-ii",it+is-iss-itt-ii])/),fl )
just extend these ideas to higher dimensions. obviously not a rigorous proof but enough to show it very likely. that the minus sign is necessary. ok forgot to add but will now it gave false when the minus sign was replaced by plus.

ok u can delete the question and answers if u know how because it would not do it for me
